# Generating Subsets of a Multiset in Ascending Order of the Sums of the Elements of the Subset

Tags: algorithm, combinations, subset-sum, multiset, unordered-multiset

I am trying to come up with an algorithm where you can generate combination from a set in a order such that their sums are in increasing order. This set has to be a multiset i.e. repetition allowed.

For example you have a set S = {1,2,2,3,4,5,5}

So, rather than generating all the combinations based on number of items (say start with 1 and 2 items and finally all 7) I want to figure them out in this order:

{1}, {2}, {2}, {1,2}, {1,2}, {3}, {1,3}, {2,2}, {4}..............{1,2,2,3,4,5,5}

Why this order: Well taking sum of these subsets we can see:

{1}, {2}, {2}, {3}, {3}, {3}, {4}, {4}, {4}..............{22}

Do you know any algorithm which can do it efficiently???

Comment: Does it matter if, for example, `{3}` comes before `{1,2}`?

Comment: Well for now it doesn't matter........but I am sure that can be handled later if required. I am exploring Subset sum problem, but that's not helping :(

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89419/algorithm-wanted-enumerate-all-subsets-of-a-set-in-order-of-increasing-sums

Comment: Thanks....but that doesn't allow Multisets :(